# Comment formatting on various sites

Tags: html, formatting, format, markdown

Some sites use `` for code formatting, while some others that I use have [c][/c] for code, or [b][/b] for bold etc. Then, some other sites like YouTube use things like ** for bold and __ for italics (I think that WhatsApp uses this same convention).

What are these called? Is `` a form of Markdown and [c][/c] is a form of HTML? What is the type used by YouTube and WhatsApp called?

And what, in general, do we call this class of formatting?

Answer (score 0):

The general term for all of these types of languages would be [Lightweight Markup Languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightweight_markup_language), although that term is not actually used much. Generally, "Markup Language" will suffice.

The `[b][/b]` syntax is most likely [BBCode](https://www.bbcode.org) (although there is no `[c]` that I an aware of; I don't know what that would be).

Many markup languages (including [Markdown](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax)) make use of backticks (`` ` ``), underscores (`_`) and asterisks (`*`), and that use does not always mean the same thing. For an example of various languages, see [this table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightweight_markup_language#Comparison_of_lightweight_markup_language_syntax) on Wikipedia.

Note that some of those languages predate Markdown and may have even contributed to Markdown adopting the same behavior. Many others are newer than Markdown and could credit Markdown as their inspiration. That said, many of these markup languages which are "inspired" by Markdown are subtly different in various ways and are **not** actually Markdown. Slack and WhatsApp are two recent examples. Note that despite their similarity to Markdown, Wikipedia lists each of them as their own separate markup language due to those differences.

Finally, most of these lightweight markup languages are subsets of HTML. That is, they represent the small portion of HTML which is more commonly used in prose and are generally converted to HTML before being displayed. For example, StackOverflow converts Markdown questions, answers and comments to HTML and serves that HTML to your browser for display. [HTML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML) (HyperText Markup Language) itself uses angle brackets (`<em>italics</em>`), but so does [XML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML) (Extensible Markup Language) and various other languages. These would not be considered "lightweight."